# Search value in strong in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let inspirationObjectArray = try decoder.decode([Inspirations].self, from: data)

for inspiration in inspirationObjectArray {
    print("@@@@ \(inspiration.productCodes)")
    //showInspirationData(inspirations: product)
}
```

the code returns the result to me:

```
@@@@ Optional("683500, 800264, 803821, 500513, 508500, 805108")
```

I need to check if this result is for example: 803821. How to do it?

Comment: You can use filter to check value

Comment: I need a result in the form of true / false. Could you show a sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the usage of the `JSONDecoder`, I would assume that `inspiration.productCodes` is an optional string, therefore you could simply split it into an array and check the wanted value ("803821") by using [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains) method. Example:

```
let productCodes: String? = "683500, 800264, 803821, 500513, 508500, 805108"
let result = productCodes?.components(separatedBy: ", ").contains("803821") ?? false
print(result) // ture
```

`result` would a a *boolean* indicates to whether the `productCodes` contains "803821" (`true`) or not (`false`). In case of `productCodes` is `nil` it would be `false`.

Otherwise if you don't care about separating the string, you could directly check if it contains "803821":

```
let productCodes: String? = "683500, 800264, 803821, 500513, 508500, 805108"
let result = productCodes?.contains("803821") ?? false
print(result) // true
```

---

***Aside bar suggestion:***

If you are aiming to treat the values as numbers (integers), then I would recommend to map them into integers (instead of strings) before the check:

```
let productCodes: String? = "683500, 800264, 803821, 500513, 508500, 805108"
if let intergersArray = productCodes?.components(separatedBy: ", ").compactMap({ Int($0) }) {
    print(intergersArray) // [683500, 800264, 803821, 500513, 508500, 805108]

    let result = intergersArray.contains(803821)
    print(result) // true
}
```

That guarantees to get a *valid* match as integers; `1` should be equals to `Int("000001")!` BUT `"1"` is *not* equals to "000001"

Answer (score 0):

true/false result

```
let searchresult = inspirationObjectArray.map {$0.productCodes.contains("803821")}
```

Answer (score 0):

`productCodes` seems to be just **one** string with multiple comma separated codes. So the result cannot be one code.

For example you can check if the string contains the code string

```
let containsCode = inspirationObjectArray.first { $0.productCodes?.contains("803821") ?? false } != nil
```